# How to save audio recorded file by user input using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

My scenario, I am trying to create `audio` `record` and save file into `iPhone`    `documentdirectory`.

I have done recording functionality but I need to implement `save file` name based on user input. After `audio` `record`, If user click save button I am asking `file` name to user by `alertviewcontroller` with `textfield`.

Here, my audio file saving by `static` file name(audio.m4a) because inside `viewdidload` I implemented save document directory code but I dont know how to implement save file name based on user input within save action.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad() 
  let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
        try? session.setActive(true)
        if let basePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
            let baseComponents = [basePath,"audio.m4a"]
            if let audioURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: baseComponents) {
                var settings: [String: Any] = [:]
                self.audioURL = audioURL
                settings[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
                settings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
                settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2
                audioRecorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
            }
        }
}

@IBAction func record_click(_ sender: Any) {
        if let audioRecorder = self.audioRecorder {
            if (audioRecorder.isRecording) {
                audioRecorder.stop()
           } else {
                audioRecorder.record()
            }
        }
    }

// Within below action I am calling alertview with textfield for asking file name
@IBAction func save_click(_ sender: Any) {
   self.savefileAlertView()
}
```

Comment: Show your attempt to prompt the user and to use that entered filename.

Comment: Sorry Can't able to understand. Could you please provide some code @rmaddy

Comment: I'm asking you to provide your code. Show your attempt to display the alert view prompting the user for a filename. Then show your attempt to make use of that filename to save the audio file. Then clearly explain what help you need.

Comment: Sure I will. Thank you.@rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set name of file which has been already saved you can rename it.

You can create this function

```
func renameAudio(newTitle: String) {
    do {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let documentDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let originPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("audio.m4a")
        let destinationPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(newTitle).m4a")
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: originPath, to: destinationPath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And in your alert controller use it and as parameter pass text of text field inside alert.

Comment: thank you @Robert Dresler. I will try your answer and update you here.

Comment: renaming I think it's not good idea. Do you have anyother idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Speech

class ViewController: UIViewController,AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance()
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

var filename : String       = "audio.m4a"

@IBOutlet weak var speechBtnOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.textView.text)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
    utterance.rate = 0.1
    synthesizer.delegate = self
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)

}

func renameAudio(newTitle: String) {
    do {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let documentDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        let originPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(utterance.speechString)

        let destinationPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(newTitle).m4a")
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: originPath, to: destinationPath)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}



  @IBAction func speechBtn(_ sender: Any) {       
   }
}
```